# Is high temperature an issue with underfloor heating?

Tags: heating, floorheating

I have an underfloor heating installed and it takes significant amount of time (~2 hours) for the floor to heat up when pushing 30-35C hot water into the pipes

Is it a problem if I set a much higher temperature (such as 50-60C) and run it for a shorter time?

Comment: You'll need to consult the flooring manufacturer's specifications as to whether or not 50-60C is acceptable for that material.

Comment: Why do you even need the floor to heat up in two hours? Low-temperature systems like this are meant to be pretty much always on, not go from completely cold to hot and back again every day. If you have a high-efficiency (condensing) gas furnace for example, then producing 60 °C water once in a while is actually way less efficient that running at 30 °C all day.

Comment: If using it as intended, you might spend two hours getting it warm once in the fall, and then it's warm all winter. Treating a "slow and steady" radiant system as if it were something it's not is unwise. If you want "pump and dump" heating you want a low-mass high-temperature delivery system; floor heat is a high-mass low-temperature delivery system.

Comment: @TooTea The reason is that I have a water-water heat pump that eats 6kW/hour no matter whether it's producing 60C or 35C. Keeping it always on has produced an insane electricity bill for me. I'm considering using running it on/off at a higher temp, which would still cause the floor to float at ~35C.

Comment: @Ecnerwal What is the intended use when you have a very strong heat pump that can either be on or off? Should I program it to turn on and off every second hour?

Comment: Perhaps you need a buffer tank which can store heat from your heat pump for use by the floor.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I do have a 300 liter buffer tank currently used for hot water. I can have it reconnected to the floors (at some cost) but will 300 liters be enough (given that when I only circulate hot water it cools down about 5 degrees C per hour and there is way less tubes used for hot water than for heating).

Answer (score 3):

I have in floor heating (pex tubing in lightweight concrete) and it's inherently slow. You can't do normal "setback at night" sort of programming and expect 6-8 degrees of recovery quickly in the morning like you could with a forced air furnace.  My system also has an outdoor temp sensor that varies the temp of the water supplied to the floors. If you have a large thermal mass (like concrete), it's prone to overshoot the set point.

To be more specific to  your question:  Pushing the supply temp to 60c (140F) would not be wise even if the piping and flooring could take it.  The floor would get uncomfortably hot. 50c (122F) might be ok on coldest days.

Tell us more about your system. Boiler type? Control system? Flooring type? Type of tubing?

This may not be an **answer**, but I had too much to say to put it in comments.   I'll update this to be more consistent with an answer if you respond with more info.

Comment: If you have a really good controller, it learns how the building performs and avoids overshoot.

Comment: @SolarMike  I agree to a point. I  have adaptive intelligent recovery t-stats in my home and still got overshoot when the night time setpoint was too far from the daytime setpoint.  The most I'll do right now is 2 degrees.  A lot depends upon the installation.  If an aluminum fin system with pex under manufactured wood flooring, overshoot is less of an issue bc of low thermal mass.  2" of concrete w/pex tubing is a LOT of thermal mass and prone to over-shoot if not carefully controlled by intelligent controllers.

Comment: We have 8” concrete so the thermal mass is high and therefore the rate of change is slow, coupled with a 1200 litre water tank that is solar heated and the max water temperature into the ufh is 25 deg C - works well.

Comment: @SolarMike  Sounds like a great setup.  Where are you in this planet?  Solar heating isn't a viable option thru out the year everywhere. With 8" concrete is that slab on grade with insulation underneath? It must be.   What do you do when the solar radiation absorbed exceeds your heating needs?

Comment: In Switzerland, up above 1000m so solar input is useful in winter but not sufficient and there are panels etc such that they shade the main windows to reduce input in the summer. Also have the air intake going underground to moderate fresh air... Air coming in at -14 deg C is a bit **too** fresh...

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I have a water-water heat pump that consumes 6kW/h no matter whether it's producing 60C or 35C output. It results in an enormous electricity bill to run it round the clock - that's my first issue. It's also very loud and I have to turn it off for night time, therefore re-heating in the morning takes a lot of time and it's always cold when we wake up - that's my second issue. We have a mix of ceramic floor and wooden floor with plastic tubes filled in concrete underneath.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is the pipe material - it may become to soft and then burst due to the pressure or a rough surface could split it.

Another issue is differential heating could crack the slab if it is in concrete.